# Sensors on Galaxy Tab emulator

Tags: android, tabs, sensors, galaxy, gyroscope

I'm trying to get the orientation of a Galaxy Tab by reading the informations from various sensors.

It should be possible to get the orientation with:

- the accelerometer and the compass (magnetic field)
- the gyroscope

The emulator has accelerometer and gyroscope enabled in config.ini, but it uses API 8 (Android 2.2). The gyroscope seems to be supported in 2.3.

When I list the available sensors, I only get the accelerometer, no gyroscope or compass.

The only solution I can think of is to switch the emulator to API 9 (2.3). Is this the only solution ?

How can NOVA from Gameloft use the gyroscope ?

Comment: Everything I can see says that only the iPhone 4 version of NOVA uses the gyroscope, the Android version uses the accelerometer for equivalent functionality (which makes sense as AFAIK currently only the Nexus S and Galaxy Tab have full gyroscopes, whereas pretty much all Android phones have an accelerometer).

Comment: This questions belongs on stackoverflow.  This website is more for users of the Android OS than developers.

Comment: @GAThrawn: So, is it possible to use the gyro on the Galaxy Tab with Android 2.2? Google recommends to use accelerometer+magnetic field to get the orientation, but the Galaxy Tab doesn't list the magnetic field sensor. Maybe it's a WIP, but you can see NOVA on Galaxy Tab here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGtpPteRSs0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I tried on a Galaxy Tab 2.2 (and not the emulator), and the gyroscope works!

Answer (score 1):

The actual Galaxy Tab does include the necessary accelerometer and magnetic field sensors that you can use to obtain the three axis orientation of the device.

As it happens the hardware does also include a gyroscope, but because the device was launched as Android 2.2 it doesn't report the gyro values in a way that lets you use the 2.3 APIs.

Comment: ok, thanks. what about the gyroscope, is it possible to use it with Android 2.2 ?

Comment: I can't edit my comment to reflect your edit. I installed Samsung Galaxy Tab simulator, but it only sets hw_accelerometer and hw_gyroscope, should I also add the setting to support magnetic field aswell ?

Comment: Yes, add the magnetic field support as well.